# Error to print tree array with php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, foreach, tree

i have a big problem to u resolve, it's killing me.
See a Array response:

```
Array (
[category_id] => 1
[parent_id] => 0
[name] => Root Catalog
[is_active] => 
[position] => 0
[level] => 0
[children] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 2
                [parent_id] => 1
                [name] => AutomaBrasil
                [is_active] => 1
                [position] => 1
                [level] => 1
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [category_id] => 3
                                [parent_id] => 2
                                [name] => Automação
                                [is_active] => 1
                                [position] => 1
                                [level] => 2
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [category_id] => 4
                                [parent_id] => 2
                                [name] => Balança
                                [is_active] => 1
                                [position] => 2
                                [level] => 2
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [category_id] => 5
                                [parent_id] => 2
                                [name] => Caixa Registradora
                                [is_active] => 1
                                [position] => 3
                                [level] => 2
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [category_id] => 6
                                [parent_id] => 2
                                [name] => Gaveta de Dinheiro
                                [is_active] => 1
                                [position] => 4
                                [level] => 2
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [category_id] => 10
                                                [parent_id] => 6
                                                [name] => Acessórios
                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                [position] => 1
                                                [level] => 3
                                                [children] => Array
                                                    (
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [category_id] => 12
                                                [parent_id] => 6
                                                [name] => Gaveta de Dinheiro Automática
                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                [position] => 2
                                                [level] => 3
                                                [children] => Array
                                                    (
                                                    )

                                            )                                                                                 

                                    )

                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [category_id] => 7
                                [parent_id] => 2
                                [name] => Impressora
                                [is_active] => 1
                                [position] => 5
                                [level] => 2
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    ))
```

Until then beauty, but when i try the "foreach", it returns me this:

```
1

0

Root Catalog

0

0

Array
```

I need it to print the complete tree inside the tags `<ul> <li>`.
I'm use recursive foreach:

```
public function createTree($lists) {

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($lists as $list) {


        echo '<li>';
        echo $list['name'] . '';
        echo '</li>';


        if (is_array($list['children'])) {

            $this->createTree($list['children']);
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

U can help me? Tks!

Comment: If you said there is an error, then show us the error.  Add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to wrap the output children array into li:

Wrap the `$this->createTree($list['children']` into `echo '<li>'; $this->createTree($list['children']); echo '</li>'`